# Is it possible to supply a type converter for a static resource in WPF?

Tags: wpf, converters, staticresource

I have a newbie WPF question.

Imagine my user control has a namespace declaration like this:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

And I have resources for the user control like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <system:Int32 x:Key="Today">32</system:Int32>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And then somewhere in my user control I have this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource Today}"/>
```

This will cause an error because `Today` is defined as a integer resource, but the Text property is expecting a string.  This example is contrived, but hopefully illustrates the question.

The question is, short of making my resource type exactly match the property type, is there a way for me to provide a converter for my resources?  Something like IValueConverter for bindings or a type converter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is possible if you use a Binding.  It seems a little weird, but this will actually work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Today}}" />
```

It is because the Binding engine has built-in type conversion for the basic types.  Also, by using the Binding, if a built-in converter doesn't exist, you can specify your own.

Comment: What if you wanted to get the color components from a StatisResource which is a Color? (For instance, to change the opacity of the StaticResource color.) Doing the following doesn't seem to work: <Color A="#99" R="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}, Path=R}" G="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}, Path=G}" B="{Binding Source={StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}, Path=B}"/>

Comment: It doesn't work because you can only set a Binding on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.  Color is a struct.  You could create your own color wrapper object which is a DepdendencyProperty, and exposes A,R,G,B, and Color properties that are themselves DPs.  Changing any of the properties would update the Color property, and changing it would update all the others.

Answer (score 4):

Abe's answer should work in most situations. Another option would be to extend the `StaticResourceExtension` class :

```
public class MyStaticResourceExtension : StaticResourceExtension
{
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

    public MyStaticResourceExtension()
    {
    }

    public MyStaticResourceExtension(object resourceKey)
        : base(resourceKey)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        object value = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        if (Converter != null)
        {
            Type targetType = typeof(object);
            IProvideValueTarget target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
            if (target != null)
            {
                DependencyProperty dp = target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
                if (dp != null)
                {
                    targetType = dp.PropertyType;
                }
                else
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = target.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo;
                    if (pi != null)
                    {
                        targetType = pi.PropertyType;
                    }
                }
            }
            value = Converter.Convert(value, targetType, ConverterParameter, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! This is interesting too.  Thanks Thomas!