# WP7 Uri as StaticResource?

Tags: windows-phone-7, converters, staticresource

I want to define URI in the resource files, and use them on the **ApplicationBar**. I done it as the first answer of the following question:

> [WP7 Image Uri as StaticResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470941/wp7-image-uri-as-staticresource)

**likes:**

```
    <ResourceDictionary
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System">

        <sys:Uri x:Key="MenuButton1">/Images/button1.png</sys:Uri>
        <sys:Uri x:Key="MenuButton2">/Images/button2.png</sys:Uri>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

But it doesn't work for me, the xaml file can't be parse.

And then I found another solution that is extending the StaticResourceExtension class, see the last answer of the following question:

> [Is it possible to supply a type converter for a static resource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382178/is-it-possible-to-supply-a-type-converter-for-a-static-resource-in-wpf)

**likes:**

```
public class MyStaticResourceExtension : StaticResourceExtension
{
    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }
    public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

    public MyStaticResourceExtension()
    {
    }

    public MyStaticResourceExtension(object resourceKey)
        : base(resourceKey)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        object value = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        if (Converter != null)
        {
            Type targetType = typeof(object);
            IProvideValueTarget target = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
            if (target != null)
            {
                DependencyProperty dp = target.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;
                if (dp != null)
                {
                    targetType = dp.PropertyType;
                }
                else
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = target.TargetProperty as PropertyInfo;
                    if (pi != null)
                    {
                        targetType = pi.PropertyType;
                    }
                }
            }
            value = Converter.Convert(value, targetType, ConverterParameter, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I don't know whether it can be used on windows phone 7, and how to implement it, can someone give me some tips or example? or help me fix the first solution. **thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do this in XAML, since the ApplicationBar have no support for data-binding.

Instead, you should create the ApplicationBar with C#, which also offers you the ability of doing localization.

As for defining the URLs, I recommend you use a .NET Resource File, or define a static class with navigation URLs. The only reason for defining a URL as a resource in the first place, would be because you intend to re-use it, and as such, you're likely to also need to access it from C#, thus why a Resource File would be a optimal solution.

[Here's an example of how to build a ApplicationBar in C#](https://github.com/Windcape/DMI-Byvejr/blob/master/DMI.Weather/Views/MainPage.xaml.cs#L57). It also allows you to add more features, like transparency toggling.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Actually I have figure out the localization problem. First, defining a string in a xaml file like:
`<core:String x:Key="App...Text">refresh</core:String>`
then import the file in App.xaml and using it like:
`<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="AppBarRefreshButton" Click="AppBarRefreshButton_Click" IconUri="/Themes/.../refresh.png" Text="{StaticResource App...Text}"/>`
And it works. 
I want to do the same to the IconUri property, but defined string in xaml file can't be used on the property, and I don't know how to define a Uri in xaml file. So, that's my question.

Comment: Use `<core:Uri>` , but *again*, it's a *bad* idea.

Answer (score 0):

using the datatemplate may figure out your issue.